# How to use ngbDatepicker in for loop

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap, ngb-datepicker

I have a problem when using "ngbDatepicker" in form array. The date input cannot be opened. I think because the toggle() function cannot be called correctly.

I have tried creating toggleDate function and call toggle() by using this code

```
toggleDate(event){
  var f = new Function(event+'.toggle()');  
  f();
}
```

I have also put

```
(click)="this[toggle]()"
```

in my html input date but it doesn't work

This is my HTML Code

```
<div formArrayName="appntTimes" *ngFor="let appnts of 
   inputForm.controls.appntTimes?.value; let i = index">
   <div [formGroupName]="i">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-2 control-label col-form-label">Date</label>
        <div class="col-7">
           <div class="input-group date" >
             <input class="form-control m-b" formControlName="annceDate1" id="{{'annceDate1'+i}}" name="{{'annceDate1'+i}}" ngbDatepicker #annceDate1{{i}}="ngbDatepicker"
              placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" (click)="toggleDate($event)"/>
             <span class="input-group-addon" >
                  <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
             </span>
            </div>
           </div>
         </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have used multiple datepickers in my page and it worked perfectly but when I put it in ngFor loop and use index to define it’s name and id, It doesn’t work.

Comment: Just to clarify, your question is how you can know witch datepicker to open since you have multiple inputs and multiple datepickers?

Comment: Yes Mendy. But I have used multiple datepickers in my page and it works perfectly but when I put it in ngFor loop and use index to define it’s name, It doesn’t work so my question is how to use it in for loop.

Comment: you needn't change the reference variable or the toogle, just `<input class="form-control m-b" formControlName="annceDate1" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker"               placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" (click)="d.toggle()"/>`, a simple example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cysmkd?file=src%2Fstyles.css

Comment: Thank you so much @Eliseo it works. My issue has been resolved.